# Python Tkinter and Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Code of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fmiw.png)Whenever I try to run a program in the Python prompt that contains tkinter or turtle module code, it says it cannot run because

> module re has no attribute to compile

[image: Picture of problem]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some code to your question, that will allow users to more easily identify any errors with your code :)

Comment: Do you have a file named `re.py` lying around somewhere? What's the output of `import re; print(re.__file__)`?

Comment: Where did you write the code? and can you also share it, we can help you get unstuck more easily if you can share the code.

Comment: Hi Aran-Fey when i input 'import re; print(re.__file__)' I am able to use python and tkinter directly from the prompt but i still can't when I am trying to run programs